# Working with data frames: collecting results into one data frame in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr

In the workspace, I have 48 data frames:

```
zbp1994f, zbp1994m, zbp1994r
zbp1995f, zbp1995m, zbp1995r
......
zbp2009f, zbp2009m, zbp2009r
```

In each frame, there is a group variable (say, group). I calculate a statistic (Moran's I) by group for just one data frame, that is zbp1994f:

```
library(ape)
moranfn <- function(dta) {
    distinv <- -1/as.matrix(dist(cbind(dta$longi, dta$lati)))
    diag(distinv) <- 0
    Moran_result <- data.frame(Moran.I(dta$myvariable, distinv))
}

library(plyr)
Moran_result_1994f <- ddply(zbp1994f,"group",moranfn)
```

This gives me the Moran_result_1994f data frame, which contains the statistics by group.

```
group stat1 stat2 sd     p-value
g1    0.049 -0.01 0.012  2.55e-06
g2    0.122 -0.05 0.041  2.45e-08
......
```

My goal is to do the job for all the data frames, and make a panel data set:

```
group year stat1 stat2 sd p-value
g1    1994 ..... ..... .. .....
g1    1995 ..... ..... .. .....
g1    1996 ..... ..... .. .....
......
g1    2009 ..... ..... .. .....
g2    1994 ..... ..... .. .....
......
```

I wonder how to loop the initial procedure over the year (1994:2009) and c("f","m","r").

Comment: Create a nested list of data frames `list(1994 = list(f = zpb1994f, m = zbp1994m, r = zpb1994r), 1995 = list(f = ...))` etc, then melt this using `reshape2`, with `id.var = names(zpb1994f)`

Comment: I would do `ls(pattern = "zbp")` and then do `ldply` on that list object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use function `get` to do that in a for-loop:

```
for(i in 1994:2009){
    for(j in c("f","m","r")){
        temp <- get(paste("zbp",i,j,sep=""))
        temp_result <- ddply(temp,"group",moranfn)
        cbind(year=rep(i,nrow(temp_result)),fmr=rep(j,nrow(temp_result)),temp_result) -> temp_result
        if(i==1994 & j=="f"){temp_result -> result}
        else{rbind(result,temp_result) -> result}
        }
    }
```

That being said, the loopless `ldply` solution of Roman Luštrik seems more straightforward...

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on mnel's solution:

Make some data:

```
set.seed(123)

somelets <- letters[rep(1:5, 2)]

zbp1990f <- data.frame(x=somelets, y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))
zbp1990m <- data.frame(x=somelets, y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))
zbp1991f <- data.frame(x=somelets, y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))
zbp1991m <- data.frame(x=somelets, y=rnorm(10), z=rnorm(10))
```

Make some function that produces a data frame:

```
myfun <- function(.dat){
  med <- median(.dat$y)
  mean <- mean(.dat$z)
  result <- data.frame(stat1=med, stat2=mean)
}
```

Combine into list as suggested by mnel:

```
zbp.list <- list(`1990`=list(f=zbp1990f, m=zbp1990m), `1991`=list(f=zbp1991f, m=zbp1991m))
```

Melt into data frame:

```
library(reshape2)

zbp.df <- melt(zbp.list, id.var=names(zbp1990f))

names(zbp.df) <- c("x", "y", "z", "group", "year")
```

Apply function to each element in the data frame:

```
library(plyr)

results <- ddply(zbp.df, .(x, group, year), myfun)

head(results)

   x group year  stat1    stat2
 1 a     f 1990  0.5772947  1.5054975
 2 a     f 1991 -0.9089078  0.8848946
 3 a     m 1990 -1.3772585  0.5575522
 4 a     m 1991  0.3415841  0.2672701
 5 b     f 1990  0.1153694  0.4288322
 6 b     f 1991 -0.3054011 -0.7886498
```